# Multiple conditions on bash 'if' statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

i'm having trouble with if in bash.
basically i'm trying to do this in bash:

```
if ((x='r')&&(y='s'))||((x='s')&&(y='p')) then
echo "bluh"
```

but i've just can't find the proper way, used square brackets, 2 square brackets, round brackets.

but it just won't work...

Comment: `if [ "$x" = r ] && [ "$y" = s ] || [ "$x" = s ] && [ "$y" = p ]; then echo doh; fi`

Comment: Hi @janos ! While OP use bash, `[[ ]]` tests are more powerful (see my  edited POST with explanations)

Comment: @GillesQuenot more power than needed for the given task. But it's true that `[[` is generally recommended over `[`, I should have used that, thanks.

Comment: If OP haven't tagged bash, then it was the good way to go ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(( ))` are for *bash arithmetic*, instead you need `[[ ]]` bash test :

```
if [[ ( $x == r && $y == s ) || ( $x == s && $y == p ) ]]; then
    echo "bluh"
fi
```

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.

Comment: You can  just use `[[ ( $x == r && $y == s ) || ( $x == s && $y == p ) ]]`, no need to use more than one `[[`. (In fact, due to precedence, you don't need the inner parentheses at all).

Comment: so in bash 'and' is like multiplying and 'or' is like adding?

Comment: @AviShabat: Yes, cf Boolean algebra.

Comment: @AviShabat Also: the spaces between elements in this expression aren't there for readability; they're critical parts of the expression syntax. Don't remove any or you'll get an error or (worse) an expression that means something else.